# What is the point of using reincarnate to give a simulacrum a soul?

Tags: spells, adnd-2e, simulacrum, reincarnation

Simulacrum allows one to use the *reincarnate* spell to give it a soul.

I understand the usefulness of using *limited wish* to give it some knowledge of the original, but what good is a soul?

I looked into some books I have, but couldn't find an explanation.

#### Is this explained in some of the source material?

Comment: I've removed the "how has this worked out in your game?" since surveying personal experience makes for a type of question to avoid asking (every answer equally correct) -- that's a discussion starter or a poll for input, not a question with an answer or solution. I appreciate you appealing to GSBS, but unfortunately no amount of GSBS in answers can solve that, since answers can only be Good Subjective if they're actually providing an answer or solution to an answerable/solveable question.

Comment: @doppelgreener that is fine. I'd rather have that removed than not having that and people voote "tooo subjective".

Answer (score 7):

Creatures without a soul can't be raised or resurrected. They also can't do stuff that requires a soul (what, exactly, requires a soul depends on your DM).  Lastly, and most importantly, only creatures with souls are *living* creatures, and thus subject to a wide variety of beneficial and harmful effects, like *Chill Touch*, *Charm Monster*, *Avoidance*, and *Regenerate* while immune to a handful of others, like (notably) *Transmute Water to Dust*.

Answer (score 0):

I would postulate that it may not be specified by the rules. As you have not given the system you are using (Assumedly D&D but the rules differ greatly between the editions). From a roleplay perspective, in a world where it is generally accepted and even provable that everyone has a soul and there is an afterlife, if you are trying to reproduce or create a person, most characters would naturally want them to have a soul as it would be cruel to deny a sapient being their shot at the afterlife.

From a mechanical standpoint it is entirely possible that many, if not all clerical abilities may require some kind soul to function and certainly to cast. For example, a character with no soul would not be affected by raise dead or Resurrection as both of those bring the characters soul back from the afterlife.

In addition, at least in 3.5, a simulacrum is described as only partially real. The reincarnate would likely make it fully real.

Comment: Question tags include adnd-2e.